# oracle multiple hash partitions parallel?

Tags: sql, oracle, hash, partition

i have a pretty huge table using hash partitons:

```
create table test
 (
      custid              VARCHAR2 (16) NOT NULL
      ,channel                NUMBER(10)
      ,agent_id             CHAR(8)
      ,TIMESTAMP           DATE
 ) cache
PARTITION BY HASH(agent_id)
(
partition e1  tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e12 tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e13 tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e14 tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e15 tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e16 tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e17 tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e18 tablespace TD_RTDM
);
```

this works pretty good, when i filter on agent_id.
now i have a new level on which i need to filter, which does not include the agent_id. so i guess i need n new parallel hash partitions like this:

```
create table test
     (
          custid             VARCHAR2 (16) NOT NULL
          ,channel               NUMBER(10)
          ,agent_id            CHAR(8)
          ,TIMESTAMP           DATE
     ) cache
PARTITION BY HASH(agent_id)
(
partition e1  tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e12 tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e13 tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e14 tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e15 tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e16 tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e17 tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e18 tablespace TD_RTDM
)
PARTITION BY HASH(channel)
(
partition e1  tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e12 tablespace TD_RTDM,
partition e13 tablespace TD_RTDM
);
```

but this does not work, since its obviously not allowed to have multiple partition statements. i googled and found lots of example using subpartitions, but i think this is not what i need.

do you have any idea, how to tune the table to get both queries performant? thanks e.

Comment: Create an index on `channel`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff sure. i have plently of indeces.

Comment: Local or global indexes?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit not sure what that is, but i'll look at it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is not necessarily a performance activity.

Partitioning offers **data management** advantages, by allowing us to load subsets of data through partition exchange or remove them by dropping partitions.

Partitioning also offers us **high availability** options, provided we spread our partitions across multiple tablespaces.

Now, Partitioning can improve the performance of certain queries, through partition pruning or elimination, but only for queries which are aligned with the partition key. Other queries, ones which run against the grain of our partitioning strategy will perform neutrally or sometimes worse than they would against an unpartitioned table.

This is because Partitioning is a physical organization of the table's data.  The rows are grouped in partition key order. Clearly data cannot be sorted in two different orders simultaneously, and that's why you cannot have parallel partition keys.

There is no easy solution to this. A global index on CHANNEL may help, because they ignore the partition keys, but they come with their own burdens; some places forbid the use of global indexes. Subpartitioning can be answer but only if the key within a key makes sense. Rebuilding the table with a new partitioning scheme is theoretically possible but almost never done in real life. Try to think outside the box: maybe a separate table (perhaps index-organized) could help? Perhaps the queries which might benefit from this different key are run so rarely that they are not worth tuning.

In short, you need to understand you data and its use cases.

Comment: yeah thanks. from the use case perspective, i would need the channel a) in parallel to the agent_it and b) as a subquery. for b) i think an index is more than enough. but a) keeps me worring, since the table is already partitioned by agent_id. so querying for channel only will need to search in all partitions... :(